# events' title is not displayed in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I developed a full calendar page, in which the title of the 'holidays' event is not displayed and this happens while i give the rendering background only. It is annoying me for a while, for i do not know where am i making a mistake..

My code is as follows:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

utc: true, 
header: { 
left: 'prev,next today EventButton', 
center: 'title', 
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' 
}, 

editable: false, 
droppable: true, 

eventSources: [                        
                    {
                        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>common/calendar/show_holidays",
                        rendering : 'background',
                        type: 'POST',
                        //backgroundColor : '#A4F80E',
                        //color: '#DAF7A6',   
                        //textColor: 'black'

                    }                    
                ],
});

});
```

Through the controller, i am passing the holidays' event. In the above code if i comment the rendering - background then i get events' title.

My sample output is :-

[image: Title not displayed while rendering]

Comment: So what's the JSON output of `common/calendar/show_holidays`?

Comment: Also there's a syntax error, should be no comma after type: 'POST', if you comment out the remaining lines. Please post your JSON.

Comment: {id: 10, title: "Rajiv Gandhi Rememberence", start: "2016-05-21"}
id:10
start:"2016-05-21"
title:"Rajiv Gandhi Rememberence"

Comment: @K48,@leroydev, I posted my ajax here

Comment: @Keynes so there is an error in your ajax, the closing curly brace should be at the end, not in the middle. Your title is not inside the ajax now.

Comment: What is the version you are using?

Comment: @ShankaSMS, I use fullcalendar 2.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me..! This made the title of the event significantly.

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) { 
element.append(event.title);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also try with several ways but finally bellow code helps for me

try this

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {       

    if(event.rendering=='background'){
        $('.fc-day[data-date="' + event.date + '"]').html('&nbsp;<span style="float:left">' + event.name + '</span>');
    }
}
```

Comment: It produced the same output for me. No change seen from previous. The title is still not displayed

Comment: send this json variable form back end $event['id'] = $row->id;
$event['name'] = $row->name;
$event['date'] = $row->date;
$event['backgroundColor'] = '#1ab394';
$event['rendering'] = 'background';

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it. but when rendering the background, title didn't appear. i ended up with creating two events for the same day one for background and another for displaying title.my event array was like this.

```
$event[] = array('id' => $row->id, 
                 'name' => $row->name,
                'date' => $row->date,
                'backgroundColor' => '#1ab394',
                'rendering'=> 'background');
$event[] = array('id' => $row->id, 
                 'name' => $row->name,
                'date' => $row->date,
                'backgroundColor' => '#1ab394',
                'title' => 'Holiday');
```

one event for rendering background and another for displaying title

Comment: i have created two events for same date

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay'
        },
        //events: "Calendar.asmx/EventList",
        //defaultView: 'dayView',
        events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, 1),
            description: 'long description',
            id: 1
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
            end: new Date(y, m, 1),
            description: 'long description3',
            id: 2
        }],
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.qtip({
                content: event.description + '<br />' + event.start,
                style: {
                    background: 'black',
                    color: '#FFFFFF'
                },
                position: {
                    corner: {
                        target: 'center',
                        tooltip: 'bottomMiddle'
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I got this error when i post like this....'element.qtip' is not a function

Comment: Remove eventRender obj and try again